# Buffered reader with array string

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, bufferedreader

I am making a program that lets you know your grade (if you're a member of a class, like class sections.) This is just a basic study of arrays and I'm still on the process of learning it. Sorry for asking this (if you think this is so basic to you)

```
    import java.io.*;
    class itlog {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

    int [] student_num = {100,56,75,70,90,50};
    int student_no;
    String [] studentName = {"janet, dada, dodo, dede, didi, hihi"};
    String student;     

    BufferedReader rb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is your name?: ");
    student = rb.readLine();

    if (student.equals("janet"));
    {System.out.println("Pasok.");


    if (student.equals("dada"));
    System.out.println("Pasok.");


    if (student.equals("dodo"));
    System.out.println("Pasok.");


    if (student.equals("dede"));
    System.out.println("Pasok.");


    if (student.equals("didi"));
    System.out.println("Pasok.");

    if (student.equals("hihi"));
    System.out.println("Pasok.");

    }

    else
    System.out.println("Labas.");



    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Type your Class Ranking: ");
    student_no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    if (student_no >= 1 && student_no < 6)
    System.out.println("You're School Grade is" + " " + student_num[student_no-1]);

    else
    System.out.println("You're not a student here.");

}
}
```

As you can see, I want to make a program that if you type you're name there (for example you're janet) a word "Pasok" will be the output but if you're not a member, then it will be "Labas". I don't know what to do in the else statement of "Labas." because it keeps on saying "else without if" error. I searched the problem why and all of the answers are there are no curly braces. I tried to put it but still, there's an error. While the else statement in the "You're not a student here." is correctly functioning. What is the problem about it?

Comment: You shouldn't have a semi-colon at the end of the `if` condition: `if (student.equals("janet"));`. That said, that's not the only thing wrong here. If `student.equals("janet")` is true, then `if (student.equals("dada"))` certainly *won't* be true..

Comment: oh great! thanks! didn't notice that! my program's running now!

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above said remove the semicolon at the end of `if` statement; your real `if` statement is

```
if (student.equals("dede")) {
  ; // Empty instruction!
}
System.out.println("Pasok.");
```

a better approach may use a `Set` of students instead of having multiple `if`; less code, less errors!

```
Set<String> students = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String [] {"janet, dada, dodo, dede, didi, hihi"}));
if(students.contains(student)) {
  System.out.println("Pasok.");
}
else {
  System.out.println("Labas.");
}
```

Comment: whoah! thank you for the info! that would make my day easier! thank you :D

Comment: +1 for using HashSet to simplify code as well as answer OP's question

Answer (score 0):

```
if (student.equals("janet"))
{System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("dada"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("dodo"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("dede"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("didi"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");

if (student.equals("hihi"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");

}

else
System.out.println("Labas.");
```

In your code there shouldn't be ";"  semicolon after every if conditional statement. And still you can use the below function

```
Arrays.asList(...).contains(...)
```

to test if an array contains certain value

Answer (score 0):

package test;

import java.io.*;

class itlog {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

```
int [] student_num = {100,56,75,70,90,50};
int student_no;
String [] studentName = {"janet, dada, dodo, dede, didi, hihi"};
String student;     

BufferedReader rb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("What is your name?: ");
student = rb.readLine();

if (student.equals("janet"))
{
System.out.println("Pasok.");

if (student.equals("dada"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("dodo"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("dede"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");


if (student.equals("didi"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");

if (student.equals("hihi"))
System.out.println("Pasok.");

}
else
System.out.println("Labas.");



BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Type your Class Ranking: ");
student_no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

if (student_no >= 1 && student_no < 6)
System.out.println("You're School Grade is" + " " + student_num[student_no-1]);

else
System.out.println("You're not a student here.");
```

}
}
something like this